# How to compute set difference between subqueries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I have documents in my collection `testdb` like the following:

```
{
    "name": {
        "first": "Joe",
        "last": "Johnson"
    },
    "ssn": "1012313",
    "semester": [{
        "semesterName": "Spring2021",
        "courses": [{
                "title": "Calculus 1",
                "professor": "Erik Paulson",
                "TA": "Paul Matthews"
            },
            {
                "title": "Computer Science 1",
                "professor": "Dennis Ritchie",
                "TA": "Ken Thompson"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I would like to compute the `ssn` of all of the Students that take Calculus 1 but that do not take Computer Science 1.

To find the `ssn` of all students that take Calculus 1 I have the following query:

```
db.testcol.aggregate([
    { $match : { "semester.courses.title": "Calculus 1" } },
    { $project : { "ssn": 1, "_id": 0 } }
]);
```

and to find the `ssn` of all students that take Computer Science 1 I have:

```
db.testcol.aggregate([
    { $match : { "semester.courses.title": "Computer Science 1" } },
    { $project : { "ssn": 1, "_id": 0 } }
]);
```

I want to compute the set difference between the two sets of `ssn` which in SQL would be a simple `NOT IN` statement between two sub queries but I am having trouble finding out how to do it in Mongo.

I tried looking at `$setDifference` but it needs to work on arrays. How can I merge the two queries and find the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can condense the two queries into a single aggregation like this:

```
db.testcol.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "semester.courses.title": {
        $eq: "Calculus 1",
        $ne: "Computer Science 1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "ssn": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

The `$eq` operator looks for at least one element of the `semester.courses` array that has a `title` of `Calculus 1` and the `$ne` operator makes sure that no element has a `title` of `Computer Science 1`.